# I have implemented client side search in LWC datatable, but I want to further filter this search with client side search by column

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have implemented client side search in LWC datatable, but I want to further filter this search with search by column search as in the attached image.[image]
(i.e., whenever i select column from the select column picklist , then I should type something in the search box.)

Below is the code written for client side search,(here,I want both column search and then search).Please help
HTML

```
 <div class="slds-col">
                <div if:true={showSearchBox}>
                    <div class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small">
                        <lightning-input label="" type="search" placeholder="Search" variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleKeyChange}></lightning-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS

```
handleKeyChange(event) {
    window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
    const searchKey = event.target.value;
    if(searchKey){
        this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            //this.paginationVisibility = HIDEDIV;
            this.setPaginationControls();

            this.searchKey = searchKey;
            
            //this.recordsToDisplay = this.records.filter(rec => rec.includes(searchKey));
            //Search with any column value (Updated as per the feedback)
            this.filteredRecords = this.records.filter(rec => JSON.stringify(rec).toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase()));
            this.filtredNum = this.filteredRecords.length; 
            this.setRecordsOnPage();
        }, DELAY);
    }else{
        this.filteredRecords = this.records; 
        this.filtredNum = this.totalRecords;            
        this.paginationVisibility = SHOWDIV;
        this.setRecordsOnPage();
    }        
}
```

Comment: you've shared the code, but what is currently happening and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

you are almost there using the `this.records.filter`. The problem is that you are converting all the objects in a big string and searching for the `searchKey`.

So, if you replace it with something like the following, it should work:

```
this.filteredRecords = this.records.filter(
  (rec) => {
      return rec[searchColumn] === searchKey
  }
);
```

You can include the case-insensitiveness, etc.

As a complete example, I created a [sample project](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/8qUoAdJqs3dh8pHdsbvA).

Comment: Great that worked, Thanks a lot.. I also want to show the datatable records only when i select reusable custom search lookup in the search engine, when i select the element in search lookup engine..then only datatable records should display.(I have the custom reusable search lookup component, but how to fire the event in child whenever search record is selected). Any sample can help..Thanks

Comment: how to include case insensitiveness and also includes function in search key here? Thanks(if i search tex, it should give results like text, text1....)

Comment: Hey, Renuka, function on search key is already on sample project (check the 'onchange' handled by 'handleKeyChange'). For case-insensitiveness there are a couple of options but is probably best to check [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead of equals (e.g. `return rec[searchColumn].localeCompare(searchKey, undefined, {sensitivity: 'accent'}) === 0`).

Comment: Hi Chaves, I am getting error that localeCompare is undefined value here.

Comment: What is your browser (is it in the supported list on the link?)? Have you checked if the variable has a string value?

Comment: Hi Chaves, I am using supported version only. Can we use something like this? in below expression     this.filteredRecords = this.records.filter(rec => JSON.stringify(rec).toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase())); in  below instead of localecompare (rec) => {
      return rec[searchColumn] === searchKey.    Please help

Comment: Yes, absolutely, in some very specific locales this might give you a false positive but this should do the trick.

Comment: Chaves, Can you please implement the same in sample project if possible.

Comment: Yes, I have the 3 implemented on the sample, look at the code and let me know.

Comment: For more specific things about javascript, I recommend you to ask in the main stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Chaves, I have two components 1.custom lookup component and 2.datatable component, I want to display data in datatable based on custom lookup selection record. I tried many solutions but not working. Can you please kindly help?

Comment: Renuka - If this is a question about LWC then I suggest to search and if you cannot find your answer, post a new question with your attempt and where you have you got blocked.

Comment: Chaves.yes, I have posted it in stackoverflow.can you please look if possible...Question: Fire datatable event based on custom lookup record selection in salesforce LWC.

Comment: Chaves.yes, I have posted it in stackoverflow.can you please look if possible...Question: Fire datatable event based on custom lookup record selection in salesforce LWC.